# Foreign key reference to a table with a primary key containing 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you set a foreign key from a table to another one with a 2 column primary key in SQL referencing just one of the primary key columns Oracle?

Comment: Do you mean a two-column primary key? You can't have 2 primary keys on a table...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Foreign keys can be defined as multiple columns. However, a composite foreign key must reference a composite primary or unique key with the same number of columns and the same datatypes. Because composite primary and unique keys are limited to 32 columns, a composite foreign key is also limited to 32 columns. (in 9i, but I don't think it's different in greater versions. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm )

Comment: @Spektor - I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key must reference an entire primary key or other unique constraint.  If the parent table requires two columns to uniquely identify a record then its dependents must include both columns in their structure.

It is quite common to avoid the proliferation of compound foreign keys by using a surrogate or synthetic primary key, usally generated with a sequence.  Foreign keys reference the single column surrogate key.

The compound business key should still be enforced in the parent table with a unique constraint.

There are occasions when the compound primary key contains a column which is also unique.  For instance, this is a way of enforcing arcs, (super-type and sub-type relaionsships).  So that a PERSONS table will have (PERSON_ID) as a primary key and (PERSON_ID, PERSON_TYPE) as a unique key.  In such a scenario a dependent table might reference either (PERSON_ID) or (PERSON_ID, PERSON_TYPE) depending on the specific relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for PK-FK relation ship says that no of columns must be equal and data type should also same.

Comment: The thing about search engines is they make it very easy to find the original sources for plagiarised answers:  technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917573.aspx   Please don't attempt to garner rep by wholesale quotation: that's not the spirit of SO.